# Is this a website integrated with this iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

First of all I'm totally not advertising for this app or for this team.
I came a cross to their apps and I noticed that all their apps are using the same interface.

But what wondered me are these inside the apps are a special design websites inside their apps or what? because I'm interested how did they make it.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/awesome-laws-pro/id320196287?mt=8

By the way, I'm a Objective-c beginner and still learning.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what they do. It's easier to say what they *could* do.

They *could* be using a custom view and drawing things themselves. Or they *could* be rendering the text (quoted law) to an HTML string and loading that string into a WebView, linked with a stylesheet.